# IIS error 0x80005006 (2147463162)

Tags: c#, iis

I was told that we had an old virtual machine that had the same problem and it was fixed by downloading and installing an "iis develepor toolset".  Any idea what that "IIS developer toolset" might actually be?

IIS 7.0

This is on a windows 7 box trying to remote to a webserver and setup IIS.

```
  DirectoryEntry rvd = forms_website.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().First();
rvd.Properties["AFName"].Value = "Default Application";
```

Comment: Adding the IIS version might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# IIS Windows 7 ComException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499691/c-iis-windows-7-comexception)

Answer (score 1):

0x80005006 (2174763162) is a generic IIS property error that is thrown for a LOT of reasons. The installation of a toolkit may easily have corrected a permission setting on an extension, updated a property in the metabase, etc. This would not be a directed fix so much as a lucky one as it is possible that the error being thrown was completely unrelated to the tool set, but the update corrected an ancillary issue.

Comment: Perhaps, but we believe it has to do with the C# application doesnt have permission to do the updates

Comment: any tips or suggestions on figuring this out

Comment: @Mike Could you elaborate on `C# application doesn't have permission to do the updates?` What updates? What permissions are required?

Comment: @Mike: Perhaps, but unless you have more specific information regarding the property that was causing the error, there is no way to know for sure. This error can be generated by a LOT of things.

Comment: this is what I was told and see edit for more specific on whats throwing it:  "libs missing from the default installation that the dev version puts on to allow programmatic remote access to iis."

Comment: @Mike: My standard answer for problems such as these is to install the IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool and run a crash report. This should give you a lot more information that you won't be getting from a debug error out of IIS or a crash event in the Event Log. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en

Comment: @Joel i have the error captured in a log but I have no idea what I am looking for here...

Comment: @Mike: What generated the error? If you're talking about the Event Log or the IIS throw error that indicates 0x8.... then you don't have anything. You have the end result, not a log that is generated by the cause.

Comment: It doesnt generatore 0x8 infact it only gives me KERNELBASE!RaiseException+58 in C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused a CLR Exception of type (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) on thread 11

Comment: @Mike: IIS Debug Diagnostics may give you more information with a stack trace to boot.

Comment: @Joel, the link you gave me sends me to Debug Diagnostic Tool v1.1 and that is whats received when creating a crash rule

Comment: @Joel, guess i'm out of options.